# Set minimum font size for map label

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I render a mapbox in my reactjs web app. I would like to specify the minimum font size for map labels. Is there a way to do this without modifying every text label font size individually?

This is for my project IRLMap.com, which lets users create maps for print. When I generate a large, high-resolution poster, the labels come out way too tiny (see image).

[image]

Comment: There is not a style-spec option for setting minimum font-size, so you'll have to do it manually either in Mapbox Studio or with Mapbox GL JS that would look something like: `if (map.getLayoutProperty('layerid', 'text-size') < minTextSize)  map.setLayoutProperty('layerid', 'text-size', minTextSize);`

Comment: You should make that an answer @mollymerp ?